# PHP get key of parent array

Tags: php

My array is built in this format:

```
$my_array = array(
     1 => array('Pizza','9.99','New_York'),
     2 => array('Chicken Wok','12.49','New_Jersey'),
    ...
);
```

Then I fetch a database which contains meals.

How can I get the corresponding key of $my_array by knowing only the meal (e.g. my DB contains 'Chicken Wok' and I need to be able to get '2' as the key)?

Please note that I cannot change the structure of $my_array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything wrong with just doing a `foreach` loop?

```
foreach($my_array AS $key => $meal) {
    if($meal[0] == "Chicken Wok") echo "The key is: $key";
}
```

Comment: I thought there might be a more efficient way of doing it, performance-wise (my array contains about 100 lines and I'm fetching about 20 entries in the DB)

Comment: PHP can loop through arrays very efficiently, I don't think it should be a concern. The simple solutions are usually the best.

Comment: You could get fancy and write a recursive function that uses array_search(), but ultimately you're still looping through your array until you find a match, it won't save you anything.